# getting info from plutil

Tags: ios, bash, shell

I'm having trouble direction info from plutil. I want to check if a .plist contains the key CFBundleShortVersionString.  I don't think plutil has any option to test for if a key exists so I thought I would just `plutil -show file.plist >file.txt` but that just plain doesn't work. :/ So I tried to direct the plist file from stdout to file with the dump option `plutil -dump file.plist >file.txt` with no luck.  :/  I also tried directing the stdout to stderr and stderr and stdout to file.  Nothing worked.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 17):

Oneliner which doesn't depend on extra utility to install:

For macOS Monterey and later

```bash
plutil -extract CFBundleShortVersionString raw -o - ./Info.plist
```

For macOS Big Sur and earlier ([no raw format type](https://keith.github.io/xcode-man-pages/plutil.1.html#HISTORY))

```bash
plutil -extract CFBundleShortVersionString xml1 -o - ./Info.plist | sed -n "s/.*<string>\(.*\)<\/string>.*/\1/p"
```

Answer (score 11):

If you need to test your .plist for the existence of the `CFBundleShortVersionString` key, it's better to use `PlistBuddy` like this:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :CFBundleShortVersionString" 1.plist || echo "CFBundleShortVersionString doesn't exist"
```

Answer (score 3):

`plutil -extract CFBundleShortVersionString xml1 -o - App-Info.plist` command prints out the content of `CFBundleShortVersionString` property

Answer (score 0):

```
$ plutil -show StorePurchasesInfo.plist 2>&1 | grep cbk
```

returns all lines in the plist with the text 'cbk' in them. For some reason `plutil` sends its output to stderr. The above redirects stderr to stdout, so it can then be successfully piped on to `grep` (or redirected to a file, or whatever you want).

Comment: I guess this must be a different version, it has a -show flag in the OP's question as well.

Answer (score 0):

To kind of answer your question, you could create a little bash script containing:

```
#!/bin/bash

cp $1 /tmp/$$.tmp
plutil -convert xml1 /tmp/$$.tmp
cat /tmp/$$.tmp
rm /tmp/$$.tmp
```

If you call the bash script pldump make it executable with `chmod +x pldump`.  Place it somewhere in your path and use it like so:

```
tlh-m0290:Preferences paul.downs$ ./pldump com.example.plist  
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> <!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd"> 
<plist version="1.0"> 
<dict>
    <key>station.data.downloaded</key>
    <true/>
 </dict>
 </plist>
```

I can see no other way of making plutil output to stdout.

Comment: I think the `2>&1` trick in my answer above will make `plutil` output to `stdout`?

Answer (score 0):

In macOS Monterey, you can test that the keypath exists and is a string by checking the return status.

- `1` = it failed the test
- `0` = it passed

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

plutil -extract CFBundleShortVersionString raw -expect string Info.plist 2>/dev/null 1>/dev/null

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

Of course, this will also return a `1` if some other issue occurred, such as a problem opening the file.

A similar way, depending on what you need, is to ask `plutil` what the type of the value is at that keypath.

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

typeset typeofvalue=$(plutil -type CFBundleShortVersionString Info.plist 2>/dev/null)

if [ "string" = $typeofvalue ]; then
    echo "Exists"
else
    echo "Does not exist"
fi
```

Comment: Now that you already use Zsh in the Shebang, probably better to replace `[ ]` with `[[ ]]`.