# how to extract element value from arrays in plists using plutil

Tags: ios, plist

I am wondering how to extract an element value from arrays found in a .plist file in iOS using plutil. Usually with plists I can do extract a key only like

`plutil -key CFBundleName Info.plist`

However, in cases where there is an array like this structure:

```
<key>UIDeviceFamily 
  <array>
    <integer>1</integer>
    <integer>2</integer>
  </array>
</key>
```

I tried grabbing the 1st element with `plutil -key UIDeviceFamily -Array` or even `plutil -key UIDeviceFamily -Array[0]` but to no good luck. All I get is the whole array all the time, something like:

```
Array
(
  1,
  2
)
```

Can anybody help me with this issue that I am facing? I am using `plutil` for this with an iPad.

Comment: Are you using it in shell script? (Project/Build Phases)

Comment: Yes @AlekseyPotapov, I am using it in shell script, particularly Bash.

Comment: Don't you have a typo with </key> closing tag?

Answer (score 1):

[Apple official documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW11) says:

> Do not insert this key manually into your Info.plist files. Xcode
>   inserts it automatically based on the value in the Targeted Device
>   Family build setting. You should use that build setting to change the
>   value of the key.

But here is a script for you to read a Info.plist file using `defaults` shell command.
Say, you have your Info.plist in such path like: `/Desktop/YourProject/YourProject/Info.plist`

```
PLIST_FILE="Info"
PLIST_KEY="UIDeviceFamily"
PLIST_PATH="${PROJECT_DIR}/YourProject"
DICT_B=$(defaults read ${PLIST_PATH}/${PLIST_FILE} ${PLIST_KEY})
for el in $DICT_B
do
printf 'element %s\n' "$el"
done
```

And the output will be like this:

```
element: (
element: 1,
element: 2
element: )
```

Comment: Hi @Aleksey Potapov, I have googled `defaults` before. But sadly I need to run my Bash script on an iPad. This is for research purposes that's why I need to extract values from a `.plist` file running the script on the iPad itself not on a MacBook. Have you tried that? I mean, running `defaults` in iDevices? I am pretty sure `defaults` is a Mac command only.

Comment: Usually, when you run shell script in xcode build phases - this could be written on any language, swift, shell, python. And yes, it will be executed on iOS devices.

Comment: Note that `${PLIST_PATH}` needs to be an absolute path.

Comment: FYI, `defaults` no longer works on arbitrary plist files (only on preference domains now) (macOS 10.15.3). This has been [warned about](https://ss64.com/osx/defaults.html) for a while.

Answer (score 1):

On macOS Monterey, this can be done more easily with just `plutil`.

```sh
plutil -extract UIDeviceFamily.0 raw -expect integer Info.plist
```

Note that `-expect integer` is optional here, but it validates the type you expect to find at that keypath location.

You can also automate this a bit. Say you wanted the values of each element in the array. (The following assumes `zsh`.)

```sh
#!/bin/zsh

typeset count=$(plutil -extract UIDeviceFamily raw -expect array Info.plist)
for i in {1..$count}; do
    # $(($i - 1)) is some shell math to offset the 1-index to 0-index
    plutil -extract UIDeviceFamily.$(($i - 1)) raw -expect integer Info.plist
done
```

This will print each of the values in the array.

Extracting the "raw" value of an array will print the count of elements in the array.

Answer (score 0):

For macOS Big Sur and earlier without installing extra utilities (adapted from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46160882/360365)):

```
plutil -extract UIDeviceFamily xml1 -o - Info.plist | sed -n "s/.*\(<integer>.*<\/integer>\).*/\1/p" | head -n 1
```

A probably more robust solution using [xmlstarlet](https://xmlstar.sourceforge.net)<sup>1</sup>

```
plutil -extract UIDeviceFamily xml1 -o - Info.plist | xml sel -t -m '//integer[1]' -c . -n - 2> /dev/null
```

---

<sup>1. available on Homebrew: `brew install xmlstarlet`</sup>