# how to use plutil to get a value?

Tags: macos, plist

I need get value of "ProductVersion" and output: "15.1"
I have versions of plutil, but can't get the value

plutil -key ProductVersion myfile //not working

here is the myfile content:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
      <key>ProductVersion</key>
        <string>15.1</string>
        <key>SystemImageID</key>
        <string>3DD7870B-96BB-4BA1-9C54-306734147FFE</string>
        <key>Version</key>
        <string>Version</string>
    </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Help of plutil:

> ```
> -help                   Print this message
> -full                   Print an exhaustive list of options
> -verbose                Show verbose output
> -show                   Show property list data
> -keys                   List top level dictionary keys
> -create                 Create a new empty property list
>
> -key keyname            Recover value for key. Multiple uses builds keypath
> -value value            Set value for keypath
> -remove                 Remove value at keypath
> -type typeid            Type to use while setting key. Valid types are int,
>                         float, bool, json, and string (default). Use json to
>                         define arrays and dictionaries
> -convert format         Convert each property list file to selected format.
>                         Formats are xml1 and binary1 and json. Note that json
>                         files are saved to filename.json
> ```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [getting info from plutil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8778368/getting-info-from-plutil)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your plist file is malformed; the closing `</dict>` tag is duplicated. This needs to be fixed.

`plutil` as shipped with macOS 12.3 does not have a `-key` option (anymore), but you can use `PlistBuddy`:

```
/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c "Print :ProductVersion" myfile
```

Comment: For the rare need this user has for making a change in a plist file, `PlistBuddy` does the trick; thanks!

Answer (score 4):

This is how you get a value from a plist file using plutil on Mac OS 12.3.

```
plutil -extract "ProductVersion" raw myfile
```

In case you need to know the type of the value, you can first do:

```
plutil -type "ProductVersion" myfile
```